# OpenID, OAuth 2 flow for autorizating many APIs

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid, api-gateway

I have two applications/APIs exposed for SPA by Api Gateway. Each API requires its own authentication token to authenticate. What is the best way to get authentication tokens for both APIs (potentially the AG will expose more APIs that require separate authentication)?

Authentication and authorization is provided by Azure AD. AG is implemented using Istio ingress controller.

Comment: Can you specify why the backend modules require their own tokens and cannot share a single token?

Comment: They are provided by let say different vendors and each already have its own authorization policy. Very soon, we are going to integrate another external service.

Answer (score 0):

If all your backend applications use the same OAuth2 (Azure AD) system, you could use Single Sign On (SSO). User would authenticate only once - for the first token and all subsequent calls would be authenticated using a session cookie. Except for the very first authentication, when the users need to give their consent to the OAuth2 server.

So your SPA keeps a token for each backend and the process would not be annoying for users.

But there may be a catch - the OAuth2 server may find the session insufficient for authentication if it was created for different OAuth2 scopes than requested. I don't know if Azure AD has such a policy.

But if your backend applications don't need any special token scopes, just "profile" to get user info, you could use just one token for all of them. But I don't know what you mean by them having their own authorization policies which prevent them using just a single token.

Maybe there are some more sophisticated solutions, but I would just try this basic one and see if it needs some improvement.

Comment: Each API (Resource Server), validates "aud" claim. 
Each API requires dedicated set of scopes, roles, ... and even I could use one token, I don't want pass information which is not required to API call/use case.
As I understand, catch you mentioned is also case when you have single application/API. 
You shouldn't ask for all available scopes, only for that which are relevant to particular API call, so even for "one API scenario"  one token could not feet every API call.